# In R how do I set the caption to bold?

Tags: r, latex, knitr

I am using Knitr for publishing a paper. One of the requirements is that the caption including the numbering and name be made bold. For example, the entire sentence

"Figure 1: (log) project parameters distribution before and after selection."

Is this possible? I know that I can bold just the text part excluding 'Figure 1:', but that is not acceptable by the publishers. What are my options?

Comment: I think you might be able to expand on this http://gforge.se/2014/01/fast-track-publishing-using-knitr-part-iii/ to make the whole caption line bold. It has the "Figure #" bold as the example but it looks like you can have it apply to the whole line the way it describes.

Comment: Can you provide a fully reproducible example? Because this seems like something easily changed in your LaTeX preamble.

Comment: @Thomas thank you for that suggestion, that led me to look for a solution in Latex instead of Knitr, and I found that I could use \usepackage[font=bf]{caption} to turn all captions bold.